# Is there any approximation expression of finite sum of exponential taylor series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Is there any approximation expression of below?
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i!}x^i$$
$n$ is small like 5 or 10.

What i finally like to do is finding $x$ which satisfy $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i!}x^i=a$

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of approximation would you want? If your goal is to invert, just start out with an initial guess given by $\ln(a)$ and then use Newton's method. This might be slow if $a$ is too big; in particular, eventually $(n!a)^{1/n}$ will be a better initial guess.

Comment: The sum is approximately $e^x$.  So to get $a$, you can plug in $\ln (a)$

Comment: For a particular $n$ (such as $5$ or $10$) this is a particular polynomial of degree $n-1$, and you can use the usual techniques for finding roots of polynomials.  More might be said if you can say something about $a$: is it positive? Negative? 0? Large?  Near a certain particular value? ...

Comment: If $a=1-10^{-4}$ then $\ln(a)$ is a perfectly good approximation of $p_n^{-1}(a)$ for *all* $n$...

Comment: $a$ is about 1~15

Comment: Then yeah, $\ln(a)$ is adequate for pretty much all $n$ larger than about $2$.